# Indexing: a better way to handle "see" and "see also"?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, xindy

I'm just getting into indexing with LaTeX, and I've got a problem. When making an index, it's often necessary to make one term refer to another. When the one term is a synonym of the other (e.g. `soda` and `cola`), you index just one of the terms, and have the other refer to it, as in "cola 12, 36, 208" and "soda *see* cola". We use the `\see` command for that.

And when one term supplements another (e.g. "eagle 12, 39, *see also* bird of prey"), you index both and link them with `\seealso`.

All this is managed at the index level in publishing: "see" or "see also" are added to the *index itself* after it has been created, when it is clear what terms need to be centralized and complemented with one or more instances of `see`, etc. This is highly efficient and consistent, because you add `see` or `see also` exactly once per term. This is not just the best way to create indexes, it's the only way... outside of LaTeX.

With LaTeX, it seems that people creating indexes face the absurd and nearly impossible task of (1) knowing ahead of time which index entries will have to be cross-referenced and supplementarily referenced, and (2) tagging every single occurrence of every single such term with the cross-ref or supplementary ref.

So, for example, it seems that if you have 45 mentions of "cola" in a book, you have know how the index is going to be organized before it even exists, and then write `cola \index{cola|see{soda}}` 45 times based on this, rather than using `cola \index{cola}` everywhere and then pointing the single index entry for "cola" to "soda" just once. And if you decide that the main term should be "soda", you have to change 45 instances of `cola \index{cola|see{soda}}` to `cola \index{soda|see{cola}}`, potentially spread out across a dozen or two chapter files.

I say "it seems" above because as insane as it is, this *appears* to be the only way to make indexes in LaTeX. But I am new to this, so I ask: is this really true? Is there really no way to organize indexes properly in LaTeX ("properly" meaning the way they're done in actual publishing)? Say it ain't so!

Comment: I guess normally you don't reference _all_ occurrences of a term in the index, just the main or first entry, and possibly a few more times later on in different contexts. I would be surprised to find 'cola' in an index followed by 45 different page numbers, for example. Referencing a term once or twice presumably makes it more reasonable to add the `see` and `seealso` directives to individual `\index` commands.

Comment: Also, this is one of the many times where find and replace could be useful, with a good editor (or alternatively with some command line knowledge) you can modify all entries even in multiple files with a single click (or a single command).

Comment: @Marijn The "cola" example was just an example; I was imagining a book on soft drinks. And yes, search and replace is about the only (hacky) solution I can think of at the moment. I guess the root problem is that Knuth looked at indexes like a programmer and came up with a completely programmatic solution, when in reality an index is a separate and complete document that complements a book, and is not just a list of words and page numbers. There are actually professional indexers who study for years to be able to do this well!

Comment: @ Gil I understand that the cola was just an example, still I think that in most cases, example or not, you don't put large amounts of page numbers in the index for a single item - therefore adding crossreferences with all items themselves like `\index{cola|see{soda}}` seems sensible. Of course it would be convenient and maybe conceptually more clear if there was a separate command for linking two entries that you could put somewhere independent of the actual reference, for example `\linkentries{cola}{soda}` at the start of the document, but I'm not aware of any index packages that [...]

Comment: [...] define this, probably because the use case is not very prevalent. Regarding your remark about the nature of indexes: the idea behind TeX and one of the greatest advantages is that elements of a document are automatically generated, such as a table of contents, bibliography, and also the index. For example if an index item ends up on a different page because you add some text in front then the page number in the index is automatically updated. As such the index fits the design philosophy of TeX very well I think, i.e., as a dynamic and integral part of a document, and not as a separate

Comment: document that stands on its own. I do appreciate that making a good index requires skill and experience, and it requires more that just marking a few terms in your text, but I don't think the approach to indexing itself is the main issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Just write `cola\index{cola}` (or `\index*{cola}`) in your text, and in your document preamble put `\index{soda|see{cola}}`

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. It simply reiterates what the question explained as the current situation.

Comment: No it isn't. The OP says he has to write `\index{cola|see{cola}}` at every use, and a response says it would be useful to have a `\linkentries{cola}{soda}` command. My response says he doesn't have to do the former, and the latter is is in fact just the proper use of the `see` instruction.

Comment: The point is that the setup requires you to either (1) know in advance that `cola` will be primary and `soda` will be a `see cola` or (2) edit every single instance of `\index{cola}` 
if it later transpires that `cola` should be secondary and `soda` primary *or* that `cola` and `soda` should be separate *or* that `cola` should relate to `pop` rather than `soda` etc. Take your example, how do you index `soda`? If you write `soda\index{soda}`, you get an independent entry for `soda`. So you need `soda\index{cola}`, which requires knowing the terms' relationship in the index.